# Where I can learn Science as a whole? From nothing to relativity, thermodynamics, to quantum

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, universe

I'm a Computer Science Engineer, and I live in India.
I'm taking interests in Physics and Science, and I am much more curious about it. But I don't know where to start and where to finish (although I know Science can never be learned as whole).

I am gonna learn Science either way, if I get the resources at one place and organised as step by step it would save some time for me but if not I will only take more time but I will learn.

So, If any one's know where I can find such resources please answer.

Comment: Maybe you can start with the huge book list [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations). Once you find more specific interests, you can post a more specific question!

Comment: @Poujh Yes you're absolutely right. Although I wasn't asking for a book, I was asking for website or something where I can find a step by step topics through which I can move myself further in Physics and Science.

Comment: Try Dr. PhysicsA on you tube by Pr Bob Eagle.  It's very good from beginning to advanced.